# Exporting and Importing form QuickBooks 2011 using SSIS

Tags: ssis, export, etl, quickbooks

Problem Definition: I would like to export all the data from all the tables from QuickBooks into SQL Server 2008 database. I tried to create a SSIS and using RssBus .NET Data Provider for QuickBooks - http://www.rssbus.com/ado/quickbooks/. I am able to export data from QuickBooks Customers table into SQL Server 2008 database table by using ADO.NET (source data reader) and OLE DB Connection (for destination SQL Server).

Question: I would like to loop through all the tables on source side and then export one by one. Is it possible through SSIS package? I will really appreciate if someone can point good resource links or example or detailed instruction will be much appreciated!

Then I would like to do import from SQL Server to QuickBooks. I am expecting SSIS can be used to accomplish the import process.

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0):

You [can't loop over the tables](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar-SA/sqlintegrationservices/thread/91953088-5c08-4f35-b7de-10e3a7fdc6b4), you have to define each source and target table in advance in the package.

Of course, you always have the option of [creating packages dynamically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345167.aspx) from .NET code, so you could read the list of tables in QuickBooks then generate a package. If the table structures change a lot or if there is a very large number of tables it could be worth it (I know nothing about QuickBooks).